# camping equipment testing if no yard

Tags: hiking, camping, solo-backpacking

I am looking into getting camping equipment and doing so long term hiking. Haven't been camping in years. How would test my equipment if I live in the city? I would be hiking solo across the USA, How much should I need for such an endeavor?

Comment: Is there someplace fairly close where you can take several weekend hikes?

Comment: If you haven't camped in years, don't own any equipment, don't know what equipment you need, and don't know how to test it, then your initial goal should **NOT** be an 8000-km transcontinental solo trek. There's no harm in having it as a long-term ambition, but you need to start with simple, safe day hikes and work up gradually from there.

Answer (score 3):

I live in the city; to prepare for my Sierra backpacking trips I jam all my gear in my pack and take off walking, increasing distance as my endurance increases. I stop and eat lunch from my pack, using the actual gear. I pitch my tent in the yard at home when I get back (you can do this indoors) and sleep in it. I make dinner using my stove (careful with *this* indoors) and eating actual dehydrated meals.

This helps me me find and fix all types of issues with my gear (pack, how I pack it, ease of use, meals I like, etc.)

Most importantly it helps me determine which things I really **don't need** to bring, to save on weight.